# EF on IDBcommandInterceptor and DBDataReader

Tags: entity-framework, idbcommand

I am trying to Mock EF on `IDBcommandInterceptor`
For insert / update operations it is enough simple - I can return a `DbDataReader` made of a single field or an int
However, for select operations, if there are some "include", then the shape of the sql result is pretty ... *awesome*

How could I obtain from

`ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader>` the fields and the names and the corresponding entities for the `DbDataReader` result?

Thank you,

Example : Trying to read `Department(Id, Name) from Id with include on Employee(Id, Name .IDDepartment, DateModification, DateCreation, User)`
The  Command that obtains the DBDataReader for an include  is below .

I want to  know the fields names (like `C1`, `ID1`, `Name1` and others) to be capable of Mocking.

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project2].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Project2].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
    [Project2].[IDDepartment] AS [IDDepartment], 
    [Project2].[DateModification] AS [DateModification], 
    [Project2].[DateCreation] AS [DateCreation], 
    [Project2].[User] AS [User], 
    [Project2].[Archive] AS [Archive]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
        [Extent2].[IDDepartment] AS [IDDepartment], 
        [Extent2].[DateModification] AS [DateModification], 
        [Extent2].[DateCreation] AS [DateCreation], 
        [Extent2].[User] AS [User], 
        [Extent2].[Archive] AS [Archive], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
            FROM [dbo].[Department] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Extent2].[IDDepartment]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[Id] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the column names from the reader by doing something like this

```
var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount) .Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
```

That in the case you only need the names. If you get the whole schema for the result table, you could get it by doing this:

```
DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

And then iterate through the collection of rows in the datatable to get the properties of each column.

Does that help to answer your question?

Comment: What you say here it is how to transform a IDataReader into an datatable . Please read again the question - I do not have a IDataReader - nor I want to run the DbCommand to the database.